# Short cut to MCQs

Tags: memoir, auto-multiple-choice

Is there a way to get rid of typing `\begin{question}`, `\choice` for every question in multiple choice questions in LaTeX? Because I have to type hundreds of questions.

Comment: maybe you can use excel do that. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf5b4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf5b4.jpg)

Comment: Use a better editor. Many editors allow you to make templates and assign them to short cuts. If you already have a bank of questions, I'd just write a program that generates the LaTeX code.